# Div not spreading to the height of a floating image

Tags: html, css

I try to have a div spread to the height of the image it contains. Since the image has a float:left style, the div does not spread. Is there a workaround?

Here is my css code:

```css
.Small-im {float:left;height:auto; width:100px; border: solid 1px #F00;}
.click {border: solid 1px #000; height:100%;}
```

Here is my html:

```
<div class="click"><img class="Small-im" src="http://www.MenuSvp.com/i/2/p/b01.jpg"    onerror="imgError(this)" />du testssdw re sad sda asfd sfda asd asdf sdf sadf sadf sfda asdf asdff gh ru er6y reu eu uy er tre er t rt</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZjzZX/)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto` to the container (`.click`) to adjust it's size according to the floated inner content :

```css
.click {border: solid 1px #000; overflow:auto}
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZjzZX/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will come back after delay to accept your answer.